# Switch between installed device drivers programmatically

Tags: python, windows, device-manager

I'm looking for a way to switch between installed drivers programmatically (python is preferred).
When I do it manually from device manager, I follow those steps:

1. Right click on the device, then I select **Update driver**
2. **Browse my computer for drivers.**
3. **Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer**
4. Select the driver I want from a list, and press next.
5. If everything was ok, I get the message **Windows has successfully updated your drivers**